# Application runs slower after going multiple times back and fourth through view controllers

Tags: swift, performance, memory, core-data

When I have this view:

[image]

And I click the backpack button I go to this view:

[image]

I can move presented items between slots by dragging them with one's finger. This is representation of hero's inventory in which we can equip him with weapons, armor and so on. Everything is stored through Core Data. Every drag-drop re-saves data and every opening of the backpack view fetches it at the start. Thus, memory shouldn't be an issue here.

But when I go back and forth through these views by clicking backpack and Back buttons for like dozens of times then I experience lack of performance if it comes to app's response time and so, item dragging is slow and drops are hard to be made. What causes this? I use touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded functions

Comment: How are you moving between the views?  Are you using segues?

Comment: yes, I use segues through @IBActions, so when the button is clicked

Comment: You should use an *unwind segue* to return to a previous view controller.  Segues (other than unwind segues) always create a new view controller.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that

Comment: vacawama is right. You are adding more and more copies of VCs on the navigation stack